# User-defined errors with nagfor preprocessor

Tags: compilation, fortran, preprocessor, nag-fortran

I'm trying to abort compilation if an unsupported fortran compiler is used. The nagfor preprocessor defines the macro `NAGFOR`, so I wrote the following test program:

```
program foo

  implicit none

#ifdef NAGFOR
  PRINT *, "Hello from nagfor"
#else
#error "Compiler not supported"
#endif

end program foo
```

When I compile with gfortran or ifort, I get the expected error message

```
$ gfortran foo.F90
foo.F90:8:2: error: #error "Compiler not supported"

$ ifort foo.F90
foo.F90(8): #error:  "Compiler not supported"
```

but nagfor gives a different error

```
$ nagfor foo.F90
NAG Fortran Compiler Release 5.3.1(907)
"foo.F90", line 8: error: unknown fpp directive.
```

I can't find any mention of how to create an error in the nagfor [fpp documentation](http://www.nag.co.uk/nagware/np/r53_doc/fpp.html) so maybe `#error` doesn't exist. In which case, is there an alternative approach to get the same effect?

Comment: `fpp` seems to not know the `#error` directive. Look in the manual what are your other possibilities.

Comment: One possible approach could be to put some obvious junk that the compiler itself would reject fatally.  Not ideal (so not answer quality), but unless you've masses to pre-processes (and so want to abort that early) it could have the same end result.  [But also, fatal aborting is not portable.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on the NAG Compiler. fpp is intended to be pretty lightweight in terms of operation (and functionality). It originates from Sun; we are using a version based on the netlib one from http://netlib.org/fortran/fdfpp.tgz.

The fpp manual (http://www.nag.co.uk/nagware/np/r60_doc/fpp.html) does not document `#error` as being supported, which you have discovered.

As francescalus suggests, the best way to acheive what you want would be with something along the lines of

```
program foo

  implicit none

#ifdef NAGFOR
  PRINT *, "Hello from nagfor"
#else
  error "Compiler not supported"
#endif

end program foo
```